# Settings of Incoming WebHooks configuration for Dynatrace and sending alert to slack channel is not working

Tags: slack, dynatrace

I am trying the Setup of Incoming WebHooks configuration for Dynatrace and sending alert to slack channel however the alert is going to a different slack channel and not to the channel i configured .

Any suggestion what might have gone wrong

I am referring this doc for setup : https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#workflows

https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/observe-and-explore/notifications-and-alerting/problem-notifications/slack-integration